# Passing multiple variables to another page in url

Tags: php, url, session, variables

I'm passing a variable to another page in a url using sessions like this but it seems that I can't concatenate another variable to the same url and retrieve it in the next page  successfully

**Page 1**

```
session_start();
$event_id = $_SESSION['event_id'];
echo $event_id;

$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . $email_address . $event_id;
```

**Page 2**

```
if (isset($_GET['event_id'])) {
$event_id = $_GET['event_id'];}
echo $event_id;
```

`echo $event_id` shows an error `Undefined variable` on page 2 but if I use just the `event_id` in the `$url` like here

```
 $url = "http://localhost/main.php?event_id=" . $event_id;
```

That works fine, but I need to be able to use both variables in the url so that page 2 can retrieve get them.

Comment: Use this: `$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . $email_address . "&event_id=" . $event_id;`

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Use the ampersand `&` to glue variables together:

```
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=$email_address&event_id=$event_id";
//                               ^ start of vars      ^next var
```

Comment: There are some security caveats you should be aware of. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13102519/166339) for details.

Comment: You should use the PHP function to build a query http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: @JvdBerg, Would you please mention, how to access these variables after passing them in the url( in any action) ?

Comment: @Seeker `$url = $_GET['email']`

Answer (score 30):

### Short answer:

This is what you are trying to do but it poses some security and encoding problems so don't do it.

```
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . $email_address . "&eventid=" . $event_id;
```

### Long answer:

All variables in querystrings need to be urlencoded to ensure proper transmission. You should never pass a user's personal information in a url because urls are very leaky. Urls end up in log files, browsing histories, referal headers, etc. The list goes on and on.

As for proper url encoding, it can be achieved using either [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) or [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php). Either one of these should work:

```
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . urlencode($email_address) . "&eventid=" . urlencode($event_id);
```

or

```
$vars = array('email' => $email_address, 'event_id' => $event_id);
$querystring = http_build_query($vars);
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?" . $querystring;
```

Additionally, if `$event_id` is in your session, you don't actually need to pass it around in order to access it from different pages. Just call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) and it should be available.

Comment: As short answer, why not post: `$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . urlencode($email_address) . "&eventid=" . urlencode($event_id);` in there without explanation. Then at Long answer you can explain it? The short answer right now isn't recommended anyway so it doesn't add anything compared to the other short answer.

Comment: Would you please mention how to access them. Can we do it this way?
$var= $this->params->fromRoute('event_id'); and 
$var2= $this->params->fromRoute('email_address');

tnkx

Comment: @Seeker that would really depend on what PHP MVC framework you are using. There are many.

Answer (score 7):

Your first variable declartion must start with a `?` while any additional must be concatenated with a `&`

- single variable URL

  http://www.example.com/page?var=foo
- multiple variable URL

  http://www.example.com/page?var=foo&var2=bar

Answer (score 4):

```
<a href="deleteshare.php?did=<?php echo "$rowc[id]"; ?>&uid=<?php echo "$id";?>">DELETE</a>
```

Pass multiple Variable one page to another page

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple but another said you dont pass session variables through the url bar
1.You dont need to because a session is passed throughout the whole website from header when you put in header file
2.security risks
Here is first page code

`$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=" . urlencode($email_address) . "&eventid=" . urlencode($event_id);`

2nd page when getting the variables from the url bar is:

`if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['eventid']) && !empty($_GET['eventid'])){
////do whatever here
}`

Now if you want to do it the proper way of using the session you created then ignore my above code and call the session variables on the second page for instance create a session on the first page lets say for example:

```
 $_SESSION['WEB_SES'] = $email_address . "^" . $event_id;
```

obvious that you would have already assigned values to the session variables in the code above, you can call the session name whatever you want to i just used the example web_ses , the second page all you need to do is start a session and see if the session is there and check the variables and do whatever with them, example:

```
 session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION['WEB_SES'])){
 $Array = explode("^", $_SESSION['WEB_SES']);
 $email = $Array[0];
 $event_id = $Array[1]
 echo "$email";
 echo "$event_id";
 }
```

Like I said before the good thing about sessions are they can be carried throughout the entire website if this type of code in put in the header file that gets called upon on all pages that load, you can simple use the variable wherever and whenever. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You are checking `isset($_GET['event_id']` but you've not set that get variable in your hyperlink, you are just adding `email`

`http://localhost/main.php?email=" . $email_address . $event_id`

And add another GET variable in your link

```
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?email=$email_address&event_id=$event_id";
```

You did not use to concatenate your string if you are using `"` quotes

Comment: Your are a star

Answer (score 1):

Use & for this. Using & you can put as many variables as you want!

```
$url = "http://localhost/main.php?event_id=".$event_id."&email=".$email;
```

Answer (score 1):

from php.net

Warning
The superglobals `$_GET` and `$_REQUEST` are already decoded. Using `urldecode()` on an element in `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` could have unexpected and dangerous results.

link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

be careful.

Comment: How does this answer the OPs question?

Comment: i suggested that using GET or REQUEST method with none encrypted is dangerous, and send ,multi variable via page to another is very easy, with "&" it possible.