# Pagination issue in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have a simple pagination script for my search, but I'm facing some trouble.

When I change the page, the query returns to the initial definition. 
Something like:

Definition: `Select * from a;`

Search: `Select * from a where a.id = 1;`

And then when I go to the 2nd page the query becames that: `Select * from a;` again.

The code: I have a form with some fields for the search and then the script:

```
 $sqlCount_pre = "SELECT COUNT('*') FROM a ";
 $sqlCount_pre .= " INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id ";
 if( sizeof( $where ) ){
    $sqlCount_pre .= ' WHERE '.implode( ' AND ',$where );
 }

 $max = 2;
 $sqlCount = mysql_query($sqlCount_pre);
 $sqlResult = ceil(mysql_result($sqlCount, 0) / $max);
 $pg = (isset($_GET["pg"])) ? (int)$_GET["pg"] : 1 ;
 $start = ($pg - 1) * $max;
 $sqlQuery = "SELECT a.* FROM a ";
 $sqlQuery .= " INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id ";

 if( sizeof( $where ) ){
    $sqlQuery .= ' WHERE '.implode( ' AND ',$where );
    $sqlQuery .= " LIMIT $start, $max";
 }else{
    $sqlQuery .= " LIMIT $start, $max";
 }

$sql = mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then i show the result in the page.
After that i put the page links, as in this code:

```
<?php
   if($sqlResult > 1 && $pg<= $sqlResult){
       for($i=1; $i<=$sqlResult; $i++){
           echo "<a href='?pg=$i'>$i</a> ";
       }
   }       
?>
```

Is there something wrong or missing in this code?

Comment: are you escaping $pg? I'm not sure I'd be totally trusting of $pg to use it as my limit without checking it first.

Comment: isn't this: "$pg = (isset($_GET["pg"])) ? (int)$_GET["pg"] : 1 ;" the checking of the $pg? how would you do it?

Comment: instead of casting a value to an integer, which might result in something you dont want,  would you rather use is_int and not even execute the query if you were getting a non-integer. You're way seems good though. Just offering a suggestion.

Comment: @sjt003 how would you do that? can you show me in code, please? i didn't use that function before, so i don't know how to do what you telling me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you combine a search form with pagination, you need to embed the search parameters in the paging links.

```
<?php
   if($sqlResult > 1 && $pg<= $sqlResult){
       $query = $_GET;
       for($i=1; $i<=$sqlResult; $i++){
           $query['pg'] = $i;
           echo "<a href='?" . http_build_query($query) ."'>$i</a> ";
       }
   }       
?>
```

The above code takes everything in your current query string and adds in the applicable `pg` attribute when building the pagination links.

-- edit --
Combining a POST search form with pagination gets a little weird.  There are a couple things you can do:

Use javascript to populate a hidden "page" field in the form when you click one of the pagination links, and resubmit the form, e.g.:

```
$('.pagination-link').on('click', function() {
    $('#page').val($(this).html());  //where you have a hidden field #page
    $('$searchform').submit();
});
```

**OR**
Change the form method to GET, and use the example I posted above

Comment: "$query = $_GET;" Do i have to put something after the $_GET? like $_GET['something'] ? Because i tried your code and still doing the same thing.

Comment: is your search form method `POST`?

Comment: Yes it's. Why? Do i need to change something?

Comment: will something like this work? echo "<a href='?search=$searchField&pg=$i?'>$i</a>"

Comment: @ziad.ali - using a `POST` search form with pagination gets a little weird.  See my edit above

Comment: I chose to use GET instead and it's working now! Thank you @SamDufel for the help!

Answer (score 0):

is_int() doc is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

```
$pg = (isset($_GET["pg"]) && is_int($_GET["pg"])) ? (int)$_GET["pg"] : 1 ;
```

of course with this there is no reason for (int)... because we've already established $_GET["pg"] as an int, so type conversion is moot.

```
$pg = (isset($_GET["pg"]) && is_int($_GET["pg"]) &&  $_GET["pg"] > 0) ? $_GET["pg"] : 1 ;
```

this will return 1 if

```
$_GET["pg"]
```

returns a string of numbers like "42". For an alternative and is_numeric and a description and comparison of the two check out this [article](http://ocaoimh.ie/2009/03/31/php-is_numeric-vs-is_int/).

If GET returns a string

```
pg_escape_string($_GET["pg"])
```

[pg_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php) doc

Back to your original question. When you change pages the limit is not being executed. So the offset and max are not being set. take a look at the query executed when you hit the second page. Are you calculating the offset correctly?

are you only specifying $pg in

```
  echo "<a href='?pg=$i'>$i</a> ";
```

you'd have to put in the search term as well to pass it to the $where array. The count will be 0 if you don't and that's why the implode doesn't happen.

multiple variables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url)

Comment: hey @stj003. I replaced with you code doing is_int. Do i still use that: "$start = ($pg - 1) * $max;" ? About your question: I set the limit to be 2 register per page. When i open the page the query is: "SELECT a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id LIMIT 0, 2". When i try to search for something the query is:  "SELECT a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id WHERE `a`.`name` like "%joe%" LIMIT 0, 2". And then finallly when i change the page the query is: " SELECT a.* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.id= b.id LIMIT 2, 2".

Comment: the second page query looks like it would return 2 records **not** seen on the first page (i.e records 2-4, right?), but you're saying the second query returns the same records as the first, right? Your db has no duplicate records, right?

Comment: yes, my query with the search %joe% should return 4 records. I do not have duplicate records. When i move to the second page it shows me the results of the second page of the first query, got it? as you can see, in the second page the query is not applying this: "WHERE a.name like "%joe%" ".

Comment: check out my edit I think when you loop through the page names you're only supplying limit and not the search term.

Comment: riiiiight, that's make sense. But, when i have just only field for search i would pass like this: "?search=$searchField;pg=1" right? But i have more than one field and inner join, how do i do that?

Comment: @sjt003 - changing his code to use `is_int()` doesn't make it any more secure - just longer.

Comment: You will though be defaulted to $pg = 1 more often with is_int(). $pg could be set to a character and then converted to an integer not equal to one with @user3383534's code. Correct?

Comment: What if someone sets a page number of -1?

Comment: @sjt003 thank you for your help! i can't vote up for you answer because i do not have enough reputation, sorry.