# MYSQL order by how to use other name for column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

This is a segment of my PHP file, the database is MySQLi:

```
$order = $_GET["order"];

mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM table WHERE activ = '1' ORDER BY $order LIMIT $start, $end);
```

Now if I want to sort by newest, my url would look like this:

> mysite.com/index.php?order=date DESC

But this doesn't look good.

How can I use another name for date DESC, for example 'newest'?

> mysite.com/index.php?order=newest

Thank you in advance!!

Best regards.

Comment: Please provide what is the environment from which you are issuing these commands, is this PHP?  Also, provide information about what $start and $end variables are.

Comment: hey, yes its PHP and MYSQLi, $start and $end is just for my pagenavigation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The query string needs to be enclosed in `""`.

**Does the segment of code you provided work?  Some things to check if it does not:**

1) Make sure that your `$connect` information is correct.

2) Make sure that `table` is the name of your table.

3) Make sure that `activ` is a column in your table.  And the values stored there are of Boolean data type.

4) Make sure that `date` is a column in your table and the date type you are using is correctly stored in the table.

5) Note that `LIMIT` is expecting an argument of *number of records to return from some offset*, based on the variable names you are using `$start` and `$end`, I am assuming you are using `LIMIT` incorrectly.  More appropriately `$number_of_records` and `$offset`.

6) Check the error logs to see if there is an error being logged either by the database server or the domain server itself.

**Now if that query works...**

*Matt Clark* handled the rest of the question about `ASC` and `DESC` below, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35375156/4018041).  But obviously you can't just stick `ASC` or `DESC` without specifying a key to sort by, such as the column `date`.  So the query string would look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE activ = '1' ORDER BY date $order LIMIT $start, $end"
```

Another option if your queries get more complex and are not only related to sorting by date, then you might resort to providing multiple variables with your URL.

> mysite.com/index.php?sortby=date&order=newest

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE activ = '1' ORDER BY $sortby $order LIMIT $start, $end"
```

You can learn more about multiple variables in a URL from this post: [Passing multiple variables to another page in url](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102489/4018041) and others like it.

Comment: @Matt Clark Ha.  Looks like I am late to the show, nice answer Mark Clark.

Answer (score 1):

```
$order = $_GET["order"];
if ( $order == "newest" )
{
    $order = "DESC";
}
else
{
    $order = "ASC";
}
```

This would reassign the value of *order* depending on its initial value.

This would also give you a default value of *ASC* for any sort order that does not match `newest` exactly.

Note that if you end up doing something else, your posted code is very prone to SQL injection; [you should be sure to sanitize all your strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: hey there,  thank you it works :). could this be also done in different ways? yes sure i'll use mysqli real escape string for all the strings.

Comment: Be sure to upvote and accept if i've helped :) Cheers, and happy coding.

Comment: @Mark Clark, I gave you up vote, because it answers the other part of the question.  Good work.

Answer (score 0):

i think there's two ways of getting your database information here, 
but I had to clarify some of your arguments:

1). the value that you're getting from `$_GET['order']` must be `asc` or `desc`.

2). is the your query is wrong, there must be an column name after your order. 
it should be look like this `order by column_name $order`.

3). is you might be mispelled your `activ` as `active`. Anyway, i'm following your column name in my query below.

4). I don't understand what's the purpose of `$end`.

5). 
Anyway, here's an easy way of getting the information in your DB.

1. if every time the user has to insert/add some data into the table, you could simple order it by IDs.

   $query = mysqli_query($connnect, "select * from table where activ = '1' order by id $order limit by $start");
2. As your get information above. I assume that you are getting the order date. So, if the conditions really lies in the date, your query should be exactly look like this. Note: I write the date lower case so pay attention in your date column name if it is DATE or Date or date or what.

   $query = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from table where activ = '1' order by date $order limit $start");

I just mean to help. Sorry don't flame me.