# send multiple parameters using html GET method

Tags: php, html, get

Im trying to send 2 arguments to my controller method from my view using GET.

I don't know exactly how to add my 2nd argument to the action URL.

Here I am sending only 1 argument.

```
 action="/MVC/teacher/lookspecificMessage/<?= $details['person_receive_id']; ?>" method="GET">
```

However, I want to add this `<?= $details['related_message']; ?>`

I've tried using `lookspecificMessage/<?= $details['person_receive_id']; ?>&<?= $details['related_message']; ?>` but it dosen't work.

Comment: Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url

Comment: try using `action ="<?php echo "/MVC/teacher/lookspecificMessage/" . $details['person_receive_id'] . "&" . $details['related_message']; ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If URL rewriting is used, url should follow declared template.

In your case it can be

action="/MVC/teacher/lookspecificMessage/**$person_receive_id**/**$related_message**"

or

action="/MVC/teacher/lookspecificMessage/**$person_receive_id**/lookrelaredMessage/**$related_message**"

or any other form.
You should check rewriting rules to find correct template for url.

Answer (score 0):

Using URL rewriting, you can have parameters in the main URL structure like that. Although, typically, `GET` parameters are passed at the end after a question mark like so:

```
example.com/path/to/page?param=1
```

If you want more than one parameter, you use the ampersand to separate them:

```
example.com/path/to/page?param=1&foo=bar
```

In your case, it looks like your `.htaccess` file is doing some URL rewriting or your framework is doing some magic, which is automatically extracting the parameter and setting it in the `$_GET` array.

And to be clear, here is how you could do yours:

```
<?php

    // Get params
    $receiveId = (int) $details['person_receive_id'];
    $message = (string) $details['related_message'];

    // Build URL
    $url = "/MVC/teacher/lookspecificMessage/$receiveId?related_message=$message";

    // Encode URL (in case message has weird values)
    $url = urlencode($url);
?>

<form method="GET" action="<?php echo($url); ?>">
     <!-- REST OF FORM HERE -->
</form>
```