# transfer more than one variable through a button php

Tags: php, variables

I apologize for my English. I need to pass more than one variable through a button, I have only passed 1 variable but I want to pass 3.

```
< td> < a href="exportar_pdf.php?id= < ?php echo $fila['id'];?>">PDF< /td>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing multiple variables to another page in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url)

Answer (score 1):

URLS with multiple get variables look like this:

exportar_pdf.php?id=id&var2=var2&var3=var3

Hence, you can write something like this

```
<a href="exportar_pdf.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'];?>&var2=<?php ..?>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multple parameters by adding them with &(Ampersand) like

```
<a href="exportar_pdf.php?id=1&b=2&c=3">Text</a>
```

**Try this**

```
<td> <a href="exportar_pdf.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'];?>&uid=<?php echo $fila['yourSecondArgument'];?>">PDF</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can separate parameters by &

```
<td><a href="exportar_pdf.php?id=<?php echo $fila['id'];?>&name=<?php echo $fila['name'];?>">PDF</a>< /td>
```

Now you can $_GET['id'] and $_GET['name']