# Pass multiple variables to PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi i am currently having trouble to figure out how can i pass a second variable via url to a php file.

Bellow is the code

```
function getmodel()
{
    var mod = [];
    jQuery('.cells:checked').each(function()
    {
        mod.push($(this).val());   
     });
    model=mod.toString();
    var date = document.getElementById("date").value; // this is the variable that i would like to pass next to the model
    urlt='<?php echo base_url();?>excel/export.php?models='+model;
    window.location.replace(urlt);
}
```

So i have managed to pass the model, but  i would like to add the date variable to. The date is defined by the user.

Any ideas or guidance what i should look into,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing multiple variables to another page in url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102489/passing-multiple-variables-to-another-page-in-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
urlt='<?php echo base_url();?>excel/export.php?models='+model+'&yourdate='+data;
```

Please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102500/9730468).

yourdate is 2nd variable name that will pass now

Comment: thanks a a lot, it seems that i have been missing the `+` sign between the 2 variables.

Comment: `&` is a separator used between multiple variables